# wxpython file opening dialog

Tags: c++, python, user-interface, wxpython, wsgi

Why is this wxpython code giving me the following error?

self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU,self.onNewFile,self.New_File)

```
def onNewFile(self,evt):

    wx.FileDialog(None,'Choose a file',os.getcwd(),"",wx.OPEN)
    if dialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        print dialog.GetPath()
    dialog.Destroy()
```

Other codes to set up menubar and create items are there but when this is executed I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Front_End.py", line 52, in onNewFile
    wx.FileDialog(None,'Choose a file',os.getcwd(),"",wx.OPEN)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\wx\_windows.py", line 2430, in __init__
    _windows_.FileDialog_swiginit(self,_windows_.new_FileDialog(*args, **kwargs))
TypeError: String or Unicode type required
```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wx.FileDialog prototype is below

```
__init__(self, parent, id, title, pos, size, style, name)
```

you may miss one parameter. I also edit your code a bit as following.

```
def onNewFile(self,evt):

    dialog = wx.FileDialog(None,'Choose a file',os.getcwd(),"", "",wx.OPEN)
    if dialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        print dialog.GetPath()
    dialog.Destroy()
```